# Is it possible that two electric engines that has equal max rpm can work differently under load?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-engineering

Two electric engines let's say has 3000 rpm with no load, but if I say they cope with work differently: one becoming weaker than the other under load or friction. Is it possible? If yes, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy a model motor with no-load speed of 3000 rpm.  It weighs, say, 50gm and runs at, say 3volts.

You can buy an industrial motor with no-load speed of 3000 rpm.  It weighs, say, 5kg and runs at, say 300 volts.

Trust me, the big one will do things the small one won't.

The no-load speed is exactly that.  How fast does it run with no load.  Once you start to load it the question becomes how much torque can it deliver, and how much power.

The windings can only carry a certain current.  That, and the size of the magnetic core defines the torque it can deliver.   The current multiplied by the voltage gives the power available.